# Determine which OR statement selected the record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have criteria saved within the records of a `criteria` table which I'm using to create a dynamic query string which will query a `source` table and the results of that query will be inserted into a `destination` table. My goal is to also insert the id from the `criteria` table into the `destination` table if the criteria matched the record in the `source` table. If more than one criteria record matched, I'd just insert the first one.

The WHERE clause is built by *OR'ing* a number of sections together and within each section the criteria is *AND'ed* together. Something like the following:

```
insert into destinationTable(col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3
from sourceTable
where
--' begin generated code'
   (a = 525 and b = 324 and c = 4523) -- 'from criteria record 1'
or (d = 'asdf' and e = 3.43) -- 'from criteria record 2'
or (f = 234523 and g = 9823742) -- 'from criteria record 3'
etc...
--' end generated code'
```

I need to find a way to determine which is the first OR section that matched the criteria and insert the corresponding criteria id in the destination table How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could include a case statement in the Select clause that will output the first OR clause that succeeds:

```
Select ...
    , Case
        When a = 525 And b = 324 And C = 4523 Then Criteria_Row_1_Pk
        When d = 'asdf' and e = 3.43 Then Criteria_Row_2_Pk
        ....
        End As SuccessClausePk
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace the or by a union and add a column giving the criteria number

```
select col1, col2, col3, 1
from sourceTable
where
--' begin generated code'
   (a = 525 and b = 324 and c = 4523) -- 'from criteria record 1'
union all
select col1, col2, col3, 2
from sourceTable
where (d = 'asdf' and e = 3.43) -- 'from criteria record 2'
union all
select col1, col2, col3, 3
from sourceTable
where (f = 234523 and g = 9823742) -- 'from criteria record 3'
etc...
```

Comment: Nice, but couldn't this create duplicate records in the destination table?

Comment: subquery it and use Min(lastcolumn) something like    select col1, col2, col3, min(which) from (select col1..., 1 as Which from ... union... ) subq group by col1, col2, col3

Comment: Well, I could also change the UNION ALL to a UNION to do a distinct query, but I wonder if this would be as efficient as the other solutions presented?

Comment: re duplicates - the OP is not clear what happens if 2 criteria are matched

Comment: re efficiency - depends on the data and indicies so you will have to try and see.

Comment: @Mark, could you expand on what am I not clear about? My understanding is that if 'criteria record 1' and 'criteria record 2' both match a record in the source table, then it would insert that source record twice into the destination table - causing a duplicate. What is your understanding?

Comment: @adam0101m- yes but I could not see what the OP wanted done with duplicates - I have reread and now see - so take @cyberkiwi's comment

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is likely to be an index that can serve the full range of columns involved, it is likely the table will be fully scanned. Since we are going through all records, you might as well perform the determination **before** doing the filter.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, Which
FROM
(
    select col1, col2, col3,
    CASE
    --' begin generated code'
    WHEN 
       (a = 525 and b = 324 and c = 4523) -- 'from criteria record 1'
    THEN 1
    WHEN
       (d = 'asdf' and e = 3.43) -- 'from criteria record 2'
    THEN 2
    WHEN
       (f = 234523 and g = 9823742) -- 'from criteria record 3'
    THEN 3
    --' end generated code'
    END Which
    from sourceTable
) SQ
WHERE Which is not null -- remove where it didn't match any criteria
```

The form is predictable and consistent enough to be code-generation friendly

Comment: Interesting, I thought I was going to have to repeat the criteria in the CASE statement and the WHERE clause. I'll be curious to see if this performs well.

Comment: @cyberwiki We do have an index on the source table and the query will always contain at least one criteria that will use this index. Do you think this method is still viable or should we repeat the criteria in the WHERE clause?

Comment: There is no crystal ball when it comes to SQL Server. Performance always varies for all sorts of reasons, so I would test all queries and see which fits best. "at least one criteria that will use this index" is not good enough to prevent a scan, because there are other criteria that cannot use the index, and the query needs all criteria to be checked.